# Load a saved html file into a webview

Tags: android, file-io, webview

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667169/from-where-to-load-a-saved-html-in-a-webview), I am trying to load an HTML file into a webview.  This HTML file is not created at compile time, but at runtime.  I load a webpage, and cache it into storage for later use, in case the user is not internet-connected and wishes to view the information on the page.

Here is how I write the html out:

```
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("info.html", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    URL url = new URL(surl);
    InputStream is = url.openStream();

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int bufferSize = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    int len = 0;
    while ( (len = is.read(buffer)) != -1 )
    {
        byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len );
    }
    String outputString = new String(byteBuffer.toByteArray());

    fos.write(outputString.getBytes());

    fos.close();
```

I am able to open and read the HTML in a similar fashion, but for some reason, trying to load the html into the webview as a string doesn't work.  I figured it would be easier for the webview to open it as a file (since it is saved as a file anyway).  I'm unsure of the proper way to load this file now.  Here's a few methods I have tried:

```
view.loadUrl("file:///info.html");
view.loadUrl("info.html");
view.loadUrl("/info.html");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

file:///data/data/info.html

Might be just one data, but I think the local files are stored in the data section of your app.

Comment: Seems like a good solution except his example code is just so poorly documented

Comment: Near as I can tell, I implemented this properly, but i just get "The requested file was not fou.d No content provider: content://com.company.app/info.html"

Comment: Apparently, I had a typo in the content provider that was causing it to not match up